# How would you optimize this css? Perhaps with SASS or variables

Tags: css, sass, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to grasp some new css concepts and I have some ideas but I'm curious how others would optimize this css code. It's in regards to implementing custom colors in gutenberg theming.

```
.has-blue-background-color li a,
.has-blue-background-color p,
.has-blue-background-color h1,
.has-blue-background-color h2,
.has-blue-background-color h3,
.has-blue-background-color h4,
.has-blue-background-color h5,
.has-blue-background-color blockquote,
.has-blue-background-color blockquote p,
.has-blue-background-color blockquote cite,
.has-blue-background-color li,
.has-green-background-color li a,
.has-green-background-color p,
.has-green-background-color h1,
.has-green-background-color h2,
.has-green-background-color h3,
.has-green-background-color h4,
.has-green-background-color h5,
.has-green-background-color blockquote,
.has-green-background-color blockquote p,
.has-green-background-color blockquote cite,
.has-green-background-color li {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sort of css-preprocessor or postcss that allows for nesting will help you quite a lot.

```
//scss
.has {
    &-background {
        &-blue {
            &-color {
                p {...}
                li {....}
            }
        }
    }

    &-background {
        &-red {
            &-color {
                p {...}
                li {...}            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Eventually I'd even shift the verbs and ditch `color`. Simply to write less code overall. While `has-blue-background` reads better than `has-background-blue`, you save writing `-background` for each and every color you have.

```
//scss
.has {
    &-background {
        &-blue {
            p {...}
        }
        &-green {}
        &-orange {}
    }
}
```

The `&` is basically a "append" whatever follows after it to the parent class inside that nesting. Without the ampersand you just have your normal rule as you'd expect in css.

Perhaps you can even write a dynamic mixin for this, to not write the scss for all these colors, but rather use a function.

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing. I would like to use different verbs but these are default from gutenberg blocks and I'm adapting an existing theme and branding assets to mesh.